# Is there a way to route notification to the phone speaker when connected to a Bluetooth speaker?

Tags: notifications, bluetooth

I often listen to music/radio on my Bluetooth speaker.  Everytime a message is received the music mutes and I hear a very loud notification sound.  I would like the music to continue and the notification sound to play on the phone's speakers.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No, there isn't, AFAIK.